# Simple SQL statement to retrieve orders on a specific date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having trouble crafting a simple SQL query that retrieves the number of orders placed on 7/15/1998, which includes the date in the result. The label number of orders should be "OrderCount".

This is what I have got so far without success.

```
SELECT SUM(OrderT.CID) as OrderCount
FROM OrderT
WHERE OrderT.CID= #7/15/1998#;
```

Here is a screenshot of the database:

[image]

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: No errors, just a table with one attribute named "OrderCount". However, it
does not output any desired data

Comment: Use count instead of sum and OrderDate in your WHERE instead of CID ?

Comment: @xNeyte - okay that appears to work, it printed out "2", which is the right answer. thank you! 

Do you know how i can get it to print out the date as well?

Comment: You can add 'OrderDate' to your select

Comment: @xNeyte  tried it, got an error. my error states, "Your query does not include the specified expression, 'OrderDate' as part of an aggregate function."



SELECT OrderT.OrderDate, COUNT(OrderT.CID) AS OrderCount
FROM OrderT
WHERE OrderT.OrderDate= #7/15/1998#;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT OrderDate, COUNT(OrderID) AS OrderCount
FROM OrderT
WHERE OrderDate = #1998-07-15#
GROUP BY OrderDate;
```

Comment: Date value is not in Access SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This might be it:

```
SELECT OrderDate, COUNT(OrderID) AS OrderCount FROM OrderT WHERE OrderDate = #7/15/1998#
```

Comment: When I run this command it returns the result, "Your query does not include the specified expression, 'OrderDate' as part of an aggregate function

Comment: Date value is not in Access SQL syntax.

Comment: I changed this. The meaningful part of the query is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is how:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS OrderCount
FROM OrderT
WHERE OrderDate = #7/15/1998#;
```

To include order date:

```
SELECT OrderDate, Count(*) AS OrderCount
FROM OrderT
GROUP BY OrderDate
HAVING OrderDate = #7/15/1998#;
```

Comment: worked perfectly! thank you so much for dispensing your knowledge :]